# pls help me with this oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have to write a oracle SQL query where I have to check that length of string is 64 or not if it's 64 like in this string
'Lst021_23-FehlerDatenprotokoll.AenDienst2019.06.11_08.48.42.tx'  then extension of the string should be txt and we have to remove the part of string upto - also

So for the string
`'Lst021_23-FehlerDatenprotokoll.AenDienst2019.06.11_08.48.42.tx'` output will be

```
FehlerDatenprotokoll.AenDienst2019.06.11_08.48.42.txt
```

i am trying to write this query

```
SELECT 'Lst021_23-Fehler-Datenprotokoll.AenDienst.2019.06.11_08.48.42.tx'FROM Dual;
CASE 
WHEN LENGTH('Lst021_23-Fehler-Datenprotokoll.AenDienst.2019.06.11_08.48.42.tx')=64 THEN CONCAT('SUBSTR('Lst021_23-Fehler-Datenprotokoll.AenDienst.2019.06.11_08.48.42.tx',11,53)','t')
END
CASE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax issue in the script. Try this way

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN LENGTH('Lst021_23-Fehler-Datenprotokoll.AenDienst.2019.06.11_08.48.42.tx') = 64
        THEN CONCAT(SUBSTR('Lst021_23-Fehler-Datenprotokoll.AenDienst.2019.06.11_08.48.42.tx',11,53),'t')
    ELSE 'Lst021_23-Fehler-Datenprotokoll.AenDienst.2019.06.11_08.48.42.tx'
END
FROM Dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefer writing your string only once :

```
with t( str ) as
(
 select 'Lst021_23-Fehler-Datenprotokoll.AenDienst.2019.06.11_08.48.42.tx' from dual   
)    
select decode(length(str), 64, concat(str,'t'))  as "File Name"
  from t;

File Name
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Lst021_23-Fehler-Datenprotokoll.AenDienst.2019.06.11_08.48.42.txt
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/HZGJC89106)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

How about this? If length is 64, then:

- take a substring from the first hyphen (`-`) to the end of the string
- apply `regexp_replace` and substitute the last "word" (`\w+$`) with `txt` (as you said that extension has to be `txt`)

Here we go:

```
SQL> with test (id, col) as
  2    (select 1, 'Lst021_23-Fehler-Datenprotokoll.AenDienst.2019.06.11_08.48.42.tx' from dual
  3     union all
  4     select 2, 'blabla-Something-else.Which_is_64_characters_long.2019.06.12.txt' from dual
  5     union all
  6     select 3, 'This will not be "fixed" as it is shorter than 64 chars.exe'      from dual
  7     union all
  8     select 4, 'Yet another nice string-Kein_Fehler.Mitwoch.2019.06.13_22.22.com' from dual
  9     )
 10  select
 11    id,
 12    case when length(col) = 64 then
 13              regexp_replace(substr(col, instr(col, '-') + 1), '\w+$', 'txt')
 14         else col
 15    end result
 16  from test;

 ID RESULT
--- -----------------------------------------------------------------
  1 Fehler-Datenprotokoll.AenDienst.2019.06.11_08.48.42.txt
  2 Something-else.Which_is_64_characters_long.2019.06.12.txt
  3 This will not be "fixed" as it is shorter than 64 chars.exe
  4 Kein_Fehler.Mitwoch.2019.06.13_22.22.txt

SQL>
```